# Bidirectional communication between C and python subprocess

Tags: c, subprocess, pipe

I'm trying to have a C process create a python subprocess and communicate to it bidirectionally using two parallel FIFOs. I'm also reading the stdout of the python process separately (for logging purposes).

The plan is for both the Python and the C programs to operate completely independently and occasionally pass data to each other.

However, I'm having a lot of trouble getting the FIFOs that goes from C to python to work and the output itself confuses me. Basically I have no idea why my code is doing what it's doing and I'm sure this is because I just don't understand pipes at all.

**C code:**

```
int main() {
    printf("*** Starting main program ***\n");

    FILE *subprocOut = popen("python3 receiver.py", "r");

    // Make the fifo that we will write to and python will read
    const char *fifo1Name = "/tmp/demo1.fifo";
    int result = mkfifo(fifo1Name, S_IRWXU);
    if (result == 0) {
        printf("fifo1 successfully created!\n");
    }

    // Try to open fifo1
    FILE *fifo1 = fopen(fifo1Name, "w");
    if (fifo1) {
        printf("fifo1 successfully opened!\n");
    }

    // Try to open fifo2 (created and written to by python)
    const char *fifo2Name = "/tmp/demo2.fifo";
    FILE *fifo2 = fopen(fifo2Name, "r");
    if (fifo2) {
        printf("fifo2 successfully opened!\n");
    }

    // Various buffers
    const int bufSize = 1024;
    char buf1[bufSize]; // Used to read stdout of python process
    char buf2[bufSize]; // Used to read fifo2

    int running = 1;
    while (running) {
        printf("running...\n");

        // Write to the fifo (will be read by python script)
        const char* message = "Greetings from C!\n";
        fwrite(message, sizeof(char), strlen(message), fifo1);

        // Read from the fifo (contains output from python script)
        fread(buf2, sizeof(char), bufSize, fifo2);

        // Print the fifo output from python
        printf("[FIFO] %s\n", buf2);

        // Get the stdout of the python process
        if (fgets(buf1, bufSize, subprocOut) != NULL) {
            for (int i = bufSize; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (buf1[i] == '\n') {
                    buf1[i] = '\0';
                    break;
                }
            }

            printf("[PYTHON] %s\n", buf1);

            // If python printed a special token the whole program should terminate
            if (strncmp(buf1, "%TERMINATE%", bufSize) == 0) {
                running = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Close and delete both fifos

    fclose(fifo1);
    unlink(fifo1Name);

    fclose(fifo2);
    unlink(fifo2Name);

    printf("*** Terminating main program ***\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Python code:**

```
# Make fifo2
try:
    os.unlink('/tmp/demo2.fifo')
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
os.mkfifo('/tmp/demo2.fifo')
print('fifo2 successfully created!')

# Open fifo1 (we will read from this)
fifo1 = open('/tmp/demo1.fifo', 'r')
print('fifo1 successfully opened!')

# Open fifo2 (we will write to this)
fifo2 = open('/tmp/demo2.fifo', 'w')
print('fifo2 successfully opened!')

sys.stdout.flush()

# Count how many seconds our program has been running
timeTaken = 0

while True:
    print('Running...')

    fifo2.write('hello!\n')

    # THESE LINES CAUSE PROGRAM TO HANG
    #
    # lines = fifo1.readlines()
    # for line in lines:
    #     print('RECEIVED:', line)

    sys.stdout.flush()

    # Pretend the sleep is caused by heavy computation
    time.sleep(1)
    timeTaken += 1

    # If we've been running for 3 seconds, pull the plug
    if timeTaken == 3:
        print('%TERMINATE%')
        break
```

**Output:**

```
*** Starting main program ***
fifo1 successfully opened!
fifo2 successfully opened!
running...
[FIFO] hello!
hello!
hello!

[PYTHON] fifo2 successfully created!
running...
[FIFO] hello!
hello!
hello!

[PYTHON] fifo1 successfully opened!
running...
[FIFO] hello!
hello!
hello!

[PYTHON] fifo2 successfully opened!
running...
[FIFO] hello!
hello!
hello!

[PYTHON] Running...
running...
[FIFO] hello!
hello!
hello!

[PYTHON] Running...
running...
[FIFO] hello!
hello!
hello!

[PYTHON] Running...
running...
[FIFO] hello!
hello!
hello!

[PYTHON] %TERMINATE%

Process finished with exit code 13
```

The commented out lines in the infinite loop in the python code cause the program to hang for some reason. I can't seem to be able to read from the FIFO that goes from C to python.

Despite calling flush before the infinite loop in python, the `[PYTHON]` outputs that have to do with creating/opening the pipe are interleaved with the `[FIFO]` calls.

Also, `hello!` is printed 3 times per iteration of the while loop even though it should be printed once every time like how `[PYTHON] Running...` is.

Furthermore, why is `running...` from the C program printed as often as `[PYTHON] Running...` is? The python program sleeps for a second every iteration of the loop, but the C program should keep going right? What is causing the main loop in C to block?

Finally, it seems my `fclose()` and `unlink()` calls in my C program are causing a SIGPIPE signal, but how am I supposed to close and delete the FIFOs?

Comment: You can send a message to request closing from one end, and then close the other end. That said, the problem I believe is that you should use [mkfifo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html) instead of `fopen()`.

Comment: I make the fifo with `mkfifo` from both python and C, but I have to use `fopen` so that I can read from/write to them

Comment: You should test for the return of `fread` function before printing what is in `buf2` buffer. You may not send `strlen(message)` buts `strlen(message) + 1` to send the final `\0` to the sub process. You might call `pclose()` on subprocess before closing fifo (to be sure sub process is finished before going further...)